# What is the correct way to change the data of an already mounted component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am learning vue2 and came across this scenario. I render a component that contains a list of items, when I click on any of these items, another component is shown with the item's detail. When the detail component is created in the created hook, I call an api to obtain the detail data. So far so good. My problem is that after clicking on another item, the detail does not change its data. I understand it is because the created hook is not called again.

I have tried the `updated`, `beforeUpdate` hooks but in both cases I get a bad behavior I guess it is because they call the same `fetchDetail` method. Another solution that I thought was that before passing to the `selectedItem` state property in the new selected item, pass it an empty value `{}` to cause the component to be rendered. But without success

Data from parent component

```
data {
  selectedItem: {}
}
```

Method in parent component

```
displayDetailHandler({ id, title }) {
  this.selectedItem = {}; // intro provocar rerender
  this.selectedItem = { id, title };
}
```

Call to child component

```
<template v-if="Object.keys(selectedItem).length > 0">
  <Detail :item="selectedItem"></Detail>
</template>
```

Child component `created` hook

```
created() {
  this.fetchGameDays(); // call to api
}
```

What is the correct way to change the data of an already mounted component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `watch` on the changing `prop` (in your case, on `item`'s `id`):

```
watch: {
  'item.id': {
    handler(id) {
      if (id) {
        // call API, using the id
      }
    },
    immediate: true /* makes it run immediately after you set the watcher,
                     * does not wait until first change (like `created` call) */
  }
}
```

Besides, you probably want to `null`ify child data when the child component is closed, so the second time you open it it doesn't display the old data while the new API call is fetching.

As a side note, `v-if="Object.keys(selectedItem).length > 0"` can be simplfied to
`v-if="selectedItem.id"`

Comment: Thanks for the example. And the advice

Answer (score 1):

You can use [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) in vuejs
It  is basically a function that will be called every time there is a change it the data that is being watched. So sometime if it is a complex object that you are watching then you might need to use deep:true in the watch properties.